# Scrolling doesn't work in iframe in div

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, scrollbar

I'm not very good at coding and this time I couldn't even find an answer from the Internet.
I've made an iframe and placed it inside a div. I want to scroll what's inside the iframe, but for some reason I cannot scroll to the end of the page.

I'm not very good at explaining, so I hope these pictures will clear what I mean:
What I have: http://i87.photobucket.com/albums/k123/gaikotsu_/scroll.png
What I want: http://i87.photobucket.com/albums/k123/gaikotsu_/scroll2.png

As you can see, the iframe is cut at the bottom so that 3 rows of art are missing. I've tried everything I've been able to think of and it's just making me frustrated!

Here's the css for the div:

```
   #main {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.frame {
    display: block;
    border: medium none;
    position: absolute
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And here's how I've created the div/iframe:

```
<div id="main" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; position: absolute; left: 294; top: 44; border: ">
<iframe name="main" src="main.htm" height="710px" width="610px" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="frame">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I appreciate any kind of help! Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon after `position: absolute` in .frame CSS.

It makes the next line, `height:100%`, unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem.
I set

```
iframe{
    height: 100%; 
   }
```

And it worked for me.